# Mosh (UDP) over Tor, instead of SSH over Tor?

Tags: network-configuration

#### Benefit that I'm looking for:

- Tor is slow. When SSH'ing over Tor doing even the basic things takes a lot of time and concentration
- Especially painful are: editing a file or a mistyped command line because when finding the spot to edit you can't use the keyboard repeat functions and end up counting how many places to shift
- Mosh solves this problem by editing text on the client side cache and reconciling with the server in the background
- By tunneling over something SSH or VPN I'd still have the client side text editing that I'm describing. I'm ok with throwing away mosh's roaming benefit.
- I'm interested to in the Mosh client's "Instant local echo and line editing" https://mosh.org/#usage - is there is a way to tunnel / VPN the client-server traffic for Mosh's State Synchronization Protocol without modifying mosh?

#### The issue is:

- Tor does not support UDP
- Mosh does not support TCP

I could not find a guide. [This one](https://matt.traudt.xyz/posts/mosh-over-tor-RczgjEqF.html) came close yet it runs some communication over the regular Internet which kills the privacy that Tor offers.